# Get path with object keys JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I need get path with object jeys of JS. Function must pass thrught all object, even if he will deep.

Input data

```
    {
      tree1: {
        node1: 'valOfnode1',
        node2: 'valOfnode2',
        node3: 'valOfnode3',
        node4: {
          node5: 'valOfnode5',
          node6: 'valOfnode6',
          node7: {
            node8: 'valOfnode8',
            node9: 'surprize!',
          },
        }
      }
    };
```

Output data

```
    [
      ['tree1.node1': 'valOfnode1'],
      ['tree1.node2': 'valOfnode2'],
      ['tree1.node3': 'valOfnode3'],
      ['tree1.node4.node5': 'valOfnode5'],
      ['tree1.node4.node6': 'valOfNode6'],
      ['tree1.node4.node7.node8': 'valOfNode8'],
      ['tree1.node4.node7.node9': 'surprize!'], 
    ]
```

I tryed made a function, but in result i get all paths.
It is a my function. This function need for get depth of every path.

```
    const sortObject = (obj) => {
      const arr = [];
      const entries = Object.entries(obj);
      let headKey;
      
      const iter = (data) => {
        const keys = Object.keys(data);
        keys.forEach((key) => {
          if (typeof data[keys] !== 'object') {
            arr.push(`${headKey}.${keys}`);
            console.log(arr);
          } if (typeof data[keys] === 'object') {
            return iter(data[keys]);
          }
        });
      }
      
      return entries.forEach(([key, value]) => {
        headKey = key;
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
          return iter(value);
        }
      })
      console.log(arr);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursively walk by object keys and collect the paths:

```js
const obj = {
    tree1: {
        node1: 'valOfnode1',
        node2: 'valOfnode2',
        node3: 'valOfnode3',
        node4: {
            node5: 'valOfnode5',
            node6: 'valOfnode6',
            node7: {
                node8: 'valOfnode8',
                node9: 'surprize!',
            },
        }
    }
};

const paths = [];

walk(obj);

console.log(JSON.stringify(paths));

function walk(obj, path = '') {
    for (const k in obj) {
        const key = path + (path ? '.' : '') + k;
        if (typeof obj[k] === 'object') {
            walk(obj[k], key);
            continue;
        }
        paths.push([key, obj[k]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sabir отфильтруй вопросы по тэгу javascript, смотри вопросы и ответы, анализируй какие народ алгоритмы предлагает

Comment: ок спасибо попробую

Answer (score 1):

Use an array variable `stack` to store objects and their prefixes. do a `while` loop as long as there are `objects` in the `stack`. each iteration `pop` an object and its prefix from the `stack`, then loop over the properties of the object and check if the value is another object, if so push it onto the stack and update the `prefix`. Otherwise add the *key-value* pair with the concatenated `prefix` *flattened key-value pairs*:

```js
const tree = {
  tree1: {
    node1: 'valOfnode1',
    node2: 'valOfnode2',
    node3: 'valOfnode3',
    node4: {
      node5: 'valOfnode5',
      node6: 'valOfnode6',
      node7: {
        node8: 'valOfnode8',
        node9: 'surprize!',
      },
    },
  },
};

const stack = [];
const result = [];

stack.push([tree, '']);// Push initial object with an empty prefix
while (stack.length > 0) {
  const [currObj, prefix] = stack.pop();
  for (let key in currObj) {
    const value = currObj[key];
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      stack.push([value, prefix + key + '.']);
    } else {
      result.push([prefix + key, value]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: the only problem that the order of nodes isn't preserved, so from the resulting array the object structure isn't obvious. the logic that this gets paths by deep-levels, not by walking the tree.... so if you add `tree.node10` you'll see what i mean...